# Why would the order of the parameters of compling produce warning?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I was coding a very simply program which is basically hello world:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vec = {"Hello", "World"};
  for (const auto &num : vec) {
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Then I use a shell command to compile and execute the file:

```
echo "Start compling: "
g++ -std=c++11 -Werror -o test test.cpp
echo "File complied!"
echo "Start excuting: "
./test
echo "Program stopped"
```

In this way, everything is fine. But if I change the second command into:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o -Werror test test.cpp
```

The compiler gives me such warnings ( which I treat as errors ) :

```
Start compling: 
/usr/bin/ld: test: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 2 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: test: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File complied!
Start excuting: 
Hello
World
Program stopped
```

I really can't figure out why the order of the parameters would cause this.

Comment: Read the docs on the -o option.You haven't simply changed the order. You have moved one parameter into the middle of another corrupting it.

Comment: Because `-o` affects how `g++` interprets the next argument.   So `g++ -stdc++11 -o -Werror test test.cpp` tells `g++` to produce a file named `-Werror` from files `test` and `test.cpp`.   Whereas `g++ -std=c++11 -Werror -o test test.cpp` tells `g++` to produce an output file named `test` from file `test.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

The `-o` option takes an argument: the name of the output file.  This is always the command line argument that immediately follows `-o`, even if it might otherwise look like an option.

So `g++ -std=c++11 -o -Werror test test.cpp` is writing the output to a file with the unusual name of `-Werror`, and using both `test` and `test.cpp` as input files.  You can't use an executable as an input to compilation or linking and so it fails.

If you rearrange the command line arguments, make sure to keep `-o test` together.